# switch case crosses initialization fix

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I've already run my program properly but when I add switch case error occurs:

`[Error] crosses initialization of 'person p_array [size]`

I know that error occurs because I initialize person p_array[size]
on case 1 because I want size of p_array to resize
dynamically to save some space for my program to run

here is my code:

````
int main()
{
    Program people;
    int size = 0,ch;
    bool exit = false;
    
    cout << "[0] Exit"<<endl;
    cout << "[1] Create List"<<endl;
    cout << "[2] Display"<<endl;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin>>ch;
    do
    {
     switch(ch)
     {
        case 0:
             exit = true;
             break;
        case 1:
             cout << "Enter how many people should be on the list?: ";
             cin>>size;
             person p_array[size];
             people.getDetails(p_array,size);
             people.mergeSort(p_array,0,(size-1),size);
             break;
        case 2:
             people.sort_by_category(p_array,size);
             break;
     }
    }while(!exit);

return 0;
}```
````

Comment: While the linked target addresses your question, note that `person p_array[size];` is invalid C++ when `size` is a value only known at runtime. Use a `vector` instead.

Comment: If you need a dynamically sized array, most of time `std::vector` is better than dynamically allocate (`new`ed) array or variable length array (standard not supported).

Comment: I wanted to try vector but I don't know how so I used typedef struct:

Comment: Here: `typedef struct vacProgram
{
 string name, vac;
 char sex;
 int age;
}person;`